# Cannot defer close request body

Tags: go, request

Any idea why I cannot close request body? Request is returning `200` and no error but `req.Body.Close()` is throwhing **runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference**

```
clientHttp := &http.Client{}

req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://example.com/item/"+strconv.FormatInt(itemID, 10), nil)
  if err != nil {
    logrus.Error(err)
    return models.Company{}, err
  }
resp, err := clientHttp.Do(req)
 if err != nil {
    logrus.Error(err)
    return models.Company{}, err
 }

defer req.Body.Close() // <- panic!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`req` is a GET request. It has no body, so `req.Body` is nil. That's why you're getting a nil pointer dereference. Do not close `req.Body`.

Answer (score 7):

The application should close the response body, not the request body:

```
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

The `req.Body` field is set from the last argument to `http.NewRequest`.  The `req.Body` field is nil because the last argument to `http.NewRequest` is nil.

The transport closes the request body (if it's not nil) per the documentation for  [Request.Body](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.Body):

> For client requests, a nil body means the request has no
>       body, such as a GET request. The HTTP Client's Transport
>       is responsible for calling the Close method.